# Testing ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4

I'm trying to test that a class is not found with UnitTest on Android.

**What's going on:**
 1. I'm writing an android library with `transitive` dependencies which are resolved in the host application
 2. The developer may remove some dependencies for example remove all `com.example.package`
 3. I have a Factory that will try to instantiate (using reflection) an Object and catch the `ClassNotFoundException`. If the developer remove the dependencies, the exception should be thrown.
 4. I want to test this case, but all I found is issue with dependencies, not how to test for it.

**Example code I want to test**

```
try {
    sNetworkResponseBuilderClass = OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class;
} catch (Exception e){
    // <<<< I want to test this case
    new ClassNotFoundException("Unable to find OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class").printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

**library used:**  hamcrast, mockito, JUnit 4.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Is this the code that should be tested, or the test case you're trying to write?

Comment: It is not clear for me either, your "Example code" is supposed to be the code  of your factory? And what do you mean by "but all I found is issue with dependencies" in point #4?

Comment: I want to test that `OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class` throw a ClassNotFoundException, the example code is a part of my Factory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So for me the first thing you need to do is to extract the part of the code that can throw a `ClassNotFoundException` in order to be able to easily mock it, something like:

```
public Class<? extends NetworkResponseBuilder> getNetworkResponseBuilderClass()
    throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Then you can test a real factory instance using `Mockito.spy` to be able to redefine the behavior of the method `getNetworkResponseBuilderClass()` as next:

```
public void testFactoryIfNetworkResponseBuilderNotFound() {
    Factory factory = spy(new Factory());
    when(factory.getNetworkResponseBuilderClass()).thenThrow(
        new ClassNotFoundException()
    );
    // The rest of your test here
}

public void testFactoryIfNetworkResponseBuilderFound() {
    Factory factory = spy(new Factory());
    when(factory.getNetworkResponseBuilderClass()).thenReturn(
        OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class
    );
    // The rest of your test here
}
```

More details about [Mockito.spy](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)).

Comment: I was searching a way to remove a package at runtime like gradle exclude option and catch the exception in hte test

Comment: yep, but not just throw it, the be thrown by the compiler or at runtime

Comment: I think is the best think I can test. will try it and keep you posted

Comment: @HugoGresse I updated my answer to use Mockito.spy to be able to mock a real object which is better in your case

Comment: I was looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36931063/1377145

Comment: @HugoGresse if I were you I would test several times this approach first

Comment: But this will not test that the `OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class` is not here right ? As it only simulate the exception

Comment: and the Factory in my case have only static method, it's not instantiated.

Comment: @HugoGresse 1. that's right but we don't care in a Unit Test as you mentioned in your question, what I understand now is the fact that you are not interested in a unit test but in an integration test, which is totally different

Comment: @HugoGresse 2. Using only static methods is a bad practice in OOP one of the many reasons is that it is not easy to unit test, and this is a good proof of that, read this http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Comment: maybe you're right and it should be unit test :/. I will change the factory design and try with Mockito.

Comment: @HugoGresse I believe so too, your code will be easier to maintain this way so it is not a waste of time anyway

Comment: Quick question, how will you use mockito to throw an `InstantiationException` using `.getConstructors()[0].newInstance()` ?

Comment: @HugoGresse good question, I don't know, I would say that you can't as I guess that you get them by refection so you don't master their lifecycle so you cannot mock them but it is a good question maybe you should post another question

Comment: FYI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982651/testing-reflection-newinstance-exception

Answer (score 6):

Not quite sure if I understood your question correctly, but you can check with JUnit if an exception gets thrown:

```
@Test(expected=ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void testClassNotFoundException() {
    // a case where the exception gets thrown
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder** might be as follows:

```
package com.example.model;

public class OkHttpNetworkResponse {
    public static class Builder {

    }
}
```

> 3. I have a Factory that will try to instantiate (using reflection) an Object and catch the ClassNotFoundException. If the developer remove
>      the dependencies, the exception should be thrown.

**Factory Class:** which will create any object might be as follows:

```
package com.example.factory;

public class Factory {
    public static Object getInstance(String className)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

> 2. The developer may remove some dependencies for example remove all com.example.package
> 3. I want to test this case, but all I found is issue with dependencies, not how to test for it.

**FactoryTest Class:** which will test whether ClassNotFoundException is thrown or not might be as follows: N.B: please Check the comments carefully.

```
package com.example.factory;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FactoryTest {
    Factory factory;

    @Test(expected=ClassNotFoundException.class)
    public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        ClassLoader loader = FactoryTest.class.getClassLoader();
        String directory = loader.getResource(".").getPath() + "/com/example/model";
        File dir = new File(directory);
        //Checking directory already existed or not..
        assertTrue("Directory:"+dir.getPath()+" not exist",dir.exists());
          //Deleting directory 
        deleteDirectoryProgramatically(directory);
        //Checking directory already deleted or not..
        assertFalse("Directory:"+dir.getPath()+" still exist",dir.exists());
        //Now getInstance Method will throw ClassNotFoundException because OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class has been deleted programatically. 
        Factory.getInstance("OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class");
    }

    private void deleteDirectoryProgramatically(String directory) {
        File dir = new File(directory);
        System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
        String[] files = dir.list();
        for (String f : files) {
            File fl = new File(directory,f);
            System.out.println(f+ " deleted?"+fl.delete());
        }
        System.out.println(dir+ " deleted?"+dir.delete());
    }
}
```

Comment: the delete part is not working, it tried to delete `/Users/hugogresse/Documents/Dev/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/com/example/network/okhttp locally, but there is not way the library can be there as the the android sdk in it only.

Comment: @Hugi Gresse, do you want to test to delete file from Jar file for testing ClassNotFoundException? you cannot delete a class file from jar. Instead you could delete the complete jar programmatically. I tried to delete all classes under /com/example/model ie.OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class which resides on class path.

Comment: Provide the correct directory by modifying :  String directory = loader.getResource(".").getPath() + "/com/example/model"; For example: to delete jarFile: String directory = loader.getResource(".").getPath() + "/lib/Some.jar"; Please check the directory variable whether it is getting right path for the file.

Comment: I have checked in eclipse, it is working fine in my case. U can check:  U could try: eg. String directory = "com/example/model";

Comment: if the following :                                                                                //Checking directory already existed or not..
`assertTrue("Directory:"+dir.getPath()+" not exist",dir.exists());` is okey, others will work well.

Comment: I'm not running only java code but Android builded with gradle. And I can't figure which directory to pick. Should I pick the `intermediates/classes/test/debug/com/example` or the one in `intermediates/bundles/debug/classes.jar/`?

Comment: you need to write test case for testing **ClassNotFoundException** which is being thrown by **getInstance** method in my case. So for this, any class could be used for test the **getInstance's ClassNotFoundException throwing behaviour**. You dont need to test it by deleting jar file.

Comment: if You want to delete the Jar File by gradle configuation, then remove `assertTrue("Directory:"+dir.getPath()+" not exist",dir.exists());` assertion. Because it is varifying the whether the file is existed or not. It is assuming the file existed still now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110613/discussion-between-hugo-gresse-and-md-minhajur-rahman).

Comment: After discussion, it appear that neither `Class.forName("com.example.network.okhttp.OkHttpNetworkClient.class");` or `Class.forName("OkHttpNetworkClient.class")` works, throw ClassNotFoundException... It's a mistery for me

Comment: Class.forName("com.example.network.okhttp.OkHttpNetworkClient.class") will throw exception ClassNotFoundException if the OkHttpNetworkClient.class does not exist at runtime. Check whether Class.forName("..") is being called or not by debugging..

Comment: Just simple Create a new Project and copy my code.. and run.. it demonstrates the ClassNotFoundException being thrown..

Comment: Surely, but not in my project configuration, working on an Android library

Comment: Dont write : `Class.forName("com.example.network.okhttp.OkHttpNetworkClient.class") `  inside try block. If you catch Exception, and dont rethrow it again in catch block, the ClassNotFoundException will not be propagated even if it is being thrown by Class.forName method.

Comment: You could post your factory method's code so that i can find out whethter there is any mistake or not.

Comment: It seems Factory class is okey, check  that  whether **OkHttpNetworkClient.class** exists on **tv/teads/network/okhttp** directory. Then `String directory = loader.getResource(".").getPath() + "tv/teads/network/okhttp";`

Comment: if **com.example.network.okhttp.OkHttpNetworkClient.class** inside **some.jar** under **lib** folder. u have to delete **some.jar**. `String directory = loader.getResource(".").getPath() + "/lib/some.jar";`

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple issue. JUnit4 exception unit testing is given below with an example. Hope it will clarify you.

### MyNumber.java

```
public class MyNumber {
   int number;
   public MyNumber div(MyNumber rhs) {
      if (rhs.number == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot divide by 0!");
      this.number /= rhs.number;
      return this;
   }
}
```

### MyNumberTest.java

```
public class MyNumberTest {
   private MyNumber number1, number2; // Test fixtures
   @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
   public void testDivByZero() {
      System.out.println("Run @Test testDivByZero"); // for illustration
      number2.setNumber(0);
      number1.div(number2);
   }
}
```

### JUnit - Exceptions Test

To test if the code throws a desired exception, use annotation `@Test(expected = exception.class)`, as illustrated in the previous example. For your case it will be

```
/**
* Check for class not found exception
**/
@Test(expected=ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void testClassNotFoundException() {
    .....
}
```

> For better understanding, you can go through this tutorial: [Java Unit
>   Testing - JUnit & TestNG](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaUnitTesting.html). It contains full running code example
>   step by step with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

inside catch you can check the object with the instanceof operator as :

```
try {
    sNetworkResponseBuilderClass = OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder.class;
} catch (Exception e){
    if(e instanceof ClassNotFoundException){
        // here you can do the code you want in case of ClassNotFoundException thrown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is your dictionary problem. in your dictionary in test class will not have . change your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Class.forName("com.example.ClassName")***

```
try {
 Class.forName("com.example.OkHttpNetworkResponse.Builder");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  // This class was not found
}
```

See [Class.forName(String className)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))