# Testing reflection newInstance exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit, mockito

I'm using a very limited set of reflection in this piece of code:

```
public NetworkClient createNetworkClient() {
    try {
        return (NetworkClient) getNetworkClientClass().getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I test (using unit testing) that `newInstance()` **throw** an `InvocationTargetException` (and the other exception) ?

I'm currently using Mockito and Hamcrest for the rest of the UT.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. How do you want to test it? Automatic?

Comment: @Seth with unit test

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your junit test you are creating an instance of the `NetworkClient` class.  This should be in either the setUp() method (junt 3) or the @Before method (junit 4).  Whereever that is, wrap the instance in a spy()

```
classToTest = spy(new NetworkClient());
```

If you are using the `NetworkClient` default constructor, just declare the field with the @Spy annotation and Mockito will create it for you as a spy.

@Spy
   private NetworkClient classToTest;

Be sure to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in the @Before or setUp method for the annotation to work.

Once the `classToTest` field is a spy, you can mock out the
`getConstructors()` class to return your test array and have the first constructor throw the desired exception.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach can be to create a static nested class that extends `NetworkClient` in your test class that will throw an `Exception` in its constructor like this:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static class MyFailingNetworkClient extends NetworkClient {
        public MyFailingNetworkClient() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create this object");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your test case, you can use Mokito to make `getNetworkClientClass()` returns `MyFailingNetworkClient.class` *(assuming that it cannot be done with a simple setter)* as next:

```
MyObject object = spy(new MyObject());
when(object.getNetworkClientClass()).thenReturn(
    MyFailingNetworkClient.class
);
```